# Conditional Function in PHP to Return Shipping Rate

Tags: php, shopify

I have a store in Shopify that I am using an app to basically create my own conditional shipping rates. I want to have free shipping for orders over $50, but I need to exclude one single item from that condition (The item has the SKU in there you'll see AMF1234). For more info on what I'm using, here is the app [user guide](http://parcelintelligence.com.au/cs/user_guide.pdf). Here is my function:

```
function calculateshipping($DATA) {
    $_RATES = array();

    $_RATES[] = array(
        "service_name" => "Free Standard Shipping", 
        "service_code" => "FREE_STANDARD_SHIPPING", 
        "total_price" => 0, 
        "currency" => "USD",
    );

    $containsSpecialProduct = false;
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($DATA['items'] as $item) {
        if ($item['sku'] == 'AMF1234') {
            $containsSpecialProduct = true;
            $total = $total - $item['quantity']*$item['price']/100; // dividing by 100 because it returns in cents
        }
    }
```

Based on the guide, i need to `return $_RATES` to get them to show in my store as a shipping option. Coming from jQuery, this was my idea of getting it to work, but it did not:

```
    if ($total > 50) {
        return $_RATES;
    } else {
        return;
    }
```

I have also attempted initializing and returning a second empty array, `$_RATES1` but it didn't seem to make my rate appear. Since I'm not used to using PHP I don't know how else to do this: How can I properly return my rate array under the specified conditions?

Comment: Would you share how were you able to edit shipping rates on the checkout? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give a key to the shipping service like this so you know which one to return:

```
$_RATES['FreeShipping'] = array(

        "service_name" => "Free Standard Shipping", 
        "service_code" => "FREE_STANDARD_SHIPPING", 
        "total_price" => 0, 
        "currency" => "USD",
    );
```

if you don't want to give free shipping if the product with SKU = AMF1234 is in cart then:

```
foreach ($DATA['items'] as $item) {

    if ($item['sku'] == 'AMF1234') {

        $containsSpecialProduct = true;
    }
        $total = $total - $item['quantity']*$item['price']/100;
} 

if ($total > 50 && $containsSpecialProduct === false) {

        return $_RATES['FreeShipping'];
} else {

       //return a different shipping service
        return array();
}
```